# Newtonsoft reference breaks web services

Tags: asp.net, web-services

I have added a WebService to my website that references `NewtonSoft.JSON` library and it is giving me the following error:

> 'Formatting' is an ambiguous reference between 'Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting' and 'System.Xml.Formatting'

I obviously don't want to change the .NET page below, has anybody come across this issue before? Is there any way to disable the reference for WebServices?

Answer (score 0):

As you may already kinow, this happens because Formatting exists in both the namespaces you referred and the compiler is unable to distinguish it.

Why dont you CNTRL+F and Replace all Formatting to Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting or System.Xml.Formatting

Comment: Yep I'm aware of that but the refernce exists in an internal asp.net page

Comment: c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\CONFIG\DefaultWsdlHelpGenerator.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Just realised the assembly was referenced directly in the web config pages section, when I removed it it was fixed. As this was mvc 2 it should be no issue...

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As you said, it's because you have Newtonsoft.Json in your Web.config namespaces element. I actually do really want it there, because I use JsonConvert.SerializeObject in my front end in several places. It uses standard "using" syntax, so rather than find and replace throughout my code, I decided to only import that one class by using the following:

```
<add namespace="JsonConvert=Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert" />
```